Show the perpendicular dropped from the apex of a tetrahedron hits the circumcenter
Let $\triangle ABC$ be a triangle with circumcenter $O$ in plane $\alpha$.  Let $P$ be a point (not necessarily in plane $\alpha$) such that $PA = PB = PC$.  Thus, $PABC$ forms a tetrahedron.
Show that $PO$ is perpendicular to $\alpha$.  Use synthetic geometry, not analytic or coordinate.
My work so far is below.

Work so far
Clearly, $\triangle POA \cong \triangle POB \cong \triangle POC$ by SSS.  We need to show those triangle are right.  If $A, O, B$ were colinear, this would be straightforward; but they're only colinear  when $\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle.
We need to show that $$\triangle POA \cong \triangle POB \cong \triangle POC \implies \angle POA \text{ is right}$$ when $A,B,C,O$ are coplanar.
The difficulty is that any proof must work with all three triangles at once.  Indeed, two such triangles can be congruent without being right; it's only when we have three or more (or two colinear ones) that they must be right.  How do we reason about all three triangles together?
Analytically, for any line through a plane, the angle takes on a minimum $\theta$ in one direction, and as you rotate around the plane, increases to a maximum of $\pi - \theta$, then decreases down back to $\theta$ as you complete the rotation.  Thus, if the angle takes on a value $\phi$ in three or more locations, then it must be $$\phi = \theta = \pi - \theta = \pi/2.$$
But that fact is inaccessible; essentially, we're trying to prove (part of) it.

Update - Solution found!
I've found a solution, of which I request verifcation:
For any two distinct points $X, Y$, the locus of points equidistant from $X,Y$ is a plane bisecting and perpendicular to segment $XY$.
Let plane $\beta$ be this locus for $A,B$ and plane $\gamma$ for $A,C$.  Each plane is perpendicular to a line in $\alpha$.  Since $P,O$ are in both planes, their intersection must be $PO$.  And the intersection of two planes, each perpendicular to a line in a third plane $\alpha$, is a line perpendicular to $\alpha$.  QED.

What exactly is synthetic geometry in 3 dimensions?

@Pranay Any argument that could be made before Descartes and Femat ;-)

Your solution is correct... but its wording could be bettered by saying "the intersection of those planes with the horizontal plane are line segment bissectors of the basis triangle, whose common intersection point is known to be the circumcenter of the triangle"

Here is a suggested strategy:
Drop a perpendicular from $P$ to the plane $\alpha$, meeting $\alpha$ at $Q$.
Show that $AQ = BQ = CQ$ and therefore $Q$ is the circumcenter of $\triangle ABC$.
You may want to fill in some details.

Nice.  This works because from any point $P$ there exists a unique perpendicular to any plane $\alpha$.  In the meantime, I posted a different proof - perhaps you could take a look.

@SRobertJames Your update looks good to me. It's a nice construction.

$OA = OB = OC$ by definition of $O$.
$PA = PB = PC$ by given assumption.
$PO$ is the common side of all triangles $POA$, $POB$, $POC$.
The general formula of the cosinus theorem is $a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + 2ab\cos(\gamma)$.
Therefrom follows that $\gamma$ ought be the same value for all 3 base vertices $A$, $B$, $C$.
--- rk

Clearly $\gamma$ is the same.  You can show this without the Law of Cosines, simply by SSS.  But how does that show that $\gamma = \pi/2$?

If $OP$ would be inclined into one direction, then at least one of those $\gamma$s would become larger and at least one other would have to get smaller. (Best is that being seen if you assume to keep the third $\gamma$ constant. But it happens generally.)

Consider the planes of OPA,OPB, and OPC. They clearly intersect in the normal to the base plane ABC, i.e. in $\pi/2$. If $\gamma$ would be smaller (or larger) than that, and the ray OP still emmanates from O, then P cannot be a single point only.
